# Почему **kwargs нельзя располагать до *args?

Tags: python, функции

Почему возникает ошибка *invalid syntax* при изменении порядка следования **kwargs и *args?

```py
  File "<ipython-input-3-efe9f896dc4b>", line 1
    def some_function(a, b, **kwargs, *args):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Не могу найти внятного объяснения кроме "делай так, иначе будет ошибка invalid syntax"

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/482464/

Comment: Коротко: потому что *args - позиционные аргументы, а позиция аргумента отсчитывается от первого аргумента. Если до неименованного аргумента вставить именованный, будет ли неименованный первым аргументом или вторым? Еще интересней, если бы можно было смешивать неименованные и именованные аргументы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу пример более простой ситуации.
Эта функция корректна:

```
def a(arg1, arg2 = 3):
    pass
```

Эта функция содержит синтаксическую ошибку:

```
def a(arg2 = 3, arg1):
    pass
```

Причина этому - что `a(315)` полностью лишает значение по умолчанию смысла, т.к. в любом случае функции потребуется 2 аргумента, чтобы заполнить ещё и `arg1`

В ситуации с `*args` и `**kwargs` вопрос последовательности - вопрос порядка в коде (а python структурируется именно так, чтобы в коде был порядок).
Чтобы не нарушать структуру "сначала неименованные параметры, потом именованные", `**kwargs` не может идти перед `*args`